# скриншот RDC окна

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Как сделать скриншот Microsoft RDC окна? В стандартных вариантах получаю черный скрин.

```
private Bitmap Screenshot()
{
    var ScreenWidth = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
    var ScreenHeight = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
    var ScreenBmp = new Bitmap(ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight);
    var _Graph = Graphics.FromImage(ScreenBmp);
    var dc1 = GetDC(GetDesktopWindow());
    var dc2 = _Graph.GetHdc();

    BitBlt(dc2, 0, 0, ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight, dc1, 0, 0, 13369376);

    ReleaseDC(GetDesktopWindow(), dc1);
    _Graph.ReleaseHdc(dc2);
    _Graph.Dispose();
    Rectangle RecForm = default(Rectangle);
    this.Invoke(new Action(() => RecForm = axMsRdpClient7NotSafeForScripting1.RectangleToScreen(axMsRdpClient7NotSafeForScripting1.DisplayRectangle)));
    Bitmap FormBMP = ScreenBmp.Clone(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(
        RecForm.X, RecForm.Y, RecForm.Width, RecForm.Height
        ), ScreenBmp.PixelFormat);
    return FormBMP; 
}
```

Данный вариант не работаете на Win7, только на Win8.

Comment: _"в стандартных вариантах получаю черный скрин."_ -- стандартный это какой? Graphics.CopyFromScreen не работает?

Comment: не работает, то же самое

Comment: а если нажать Ctrl+PrtScn, то скиншот экрана копируется в clipboard?

Comment: да копируется но область где должен быть RDC черного цвета а на WIn7 белого

Comment: а WInAPI функция PrintWindow тоже не работает?

Comment: не пробовал, но подозреваю итог будет таким же